# python: How can I print an alphabet from a list, given a number?

Tags: python

Given a number from 1 to 26, I'm trying to return an alphabet in the corresponding position from a list.

Example:

```
Input = 1
Output = 'a'
```

I have tried the following:

```
user_input = int(input("Enter a number from 1 to 26 "))

for item in aplhabet:
    print(aplhabet.index(item[aplhabet]))
```

As expected that returns a type error because there are no integer values in my list.

What can I do to return an element from my list in which its position is equal to the users number input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ASCII conversion from integer to character, you can do it as follows,

```
n = int(input("Enter the number: "))
if(n > 0 and n < 27):
    print(chr(n + 96))
else: 
    print("Invalid input")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can index a list by its index:

```
import string
alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

user_input = int(input("Enter a number from 1 to 26 "))

if 0 < user_input <= 26:
    print(alphabet[user_input - 1])
else:
    print("please input a number between 1 and 26")
```

Comment: Not the downvoter. Your answer is wrong. When input is 1 your answer gives `b` and when its 26 you'd get IndexError.

Comment: yeap thanks, i didnt see the 1 based indexing

Comment: @QuantumMecha converting to a list is unnecessary, you can index the string `string.ascii_lowercase` directly

Comment: Yeah, but I feel like OP is struggling with the "how to index a datastructure" part. and highlighting that you can index a list is helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexing:

```py
alphabets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

user_input = int(input("Enter a number from 1 to 26: "))
print(alphabets[user_input - 1])
```

Note that you need to subtract 1, since Python uses 0-based index.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 answers. All of them are perfectly working. The answers are already given in ASCII values and string. You can do it another way. Create a dictionary of number key and it's corresponding alphabet as value. Take the input. Print the value of of the input present in the dictionary. Your code:

```
d={1:"a",2:"b",3:"c",4:"d",5:"e",6:"f",7:"g",8:"h",9:"i",10:"j",11:"k",12:"l",13:"m",14:"n",15:"o",16:"p",17:"q",18:"r",19:"s",20:"t",21:"u",22:"v",23:"w",24:"x",25:"y",26:"z"}
x=int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 26= "))
print(d[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

List1=['a' ,'b' ,'c' ,'d' ,'e' ,'f' ,'g' ,'h' ,'i' , 'j' ,'k' ,'l','m' ,'n' ,'o' ,'p' ,'q' ,'r' ,'s' ,'t' ,'u' ,'v' ,'w','x','y','z']

inputnumber = int(input("Enter Number"))
for i, number in enumerate(range(len(List1)),start=1):

```
if i == inputnumber:
        print(List1[i])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).